# Data.table: Join on ID and Date key, but want closest date before (or equal to ) date key in first table

Tags: r, data.table

I would really appreciate some help with this problem, I can't quite find a close enough example on SO.

I have two data.tables, the first, called `customer.table`, contains snapshots of members at particular at time-stamp (`AsOfDate`), and a second table called `activity.table` describing marketing campaigns sent to that customer at the `ActivityDate`.

I would like to find the most recent ActivityDate (i.e the maximum date) sent to a member prior to, or at, the AsOfDate for each record in the customer data table.

I've had a look at a few questions (a close question was this: [Handle a table with ID repetition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29988283/handle-a-table-with-id-repetition/29988428#29988428)), but I am not sure how to combine the conditional (ActivityDate < AsOfDate) with the maximum for Activity dates -- and I also want to retain all the columns for both tables in the join as I need to work out the time between the ActivityDate and AsOfDate. I still haven't got my head around when to use roll...

```
#libraries
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

#data
customer.table = structure(list(CustomerID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
4), AsOfDate = structure(c(1435622400, 1435622400, 1435622400, 
1435622400, 1435622400, 1435622400, 1435622400, 1435622400, 1435622400, 
1435622400, 1394150400), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), distance = c(2.17380476584343, 29.4024827688224, 
3.01353310956009, 18.4923143452557, 294.878606580665, 11.8870209430565, 
9.54438580030996, 24.2192034858273, 15.0069335290262, 10.4513664447137, 
18.4923143452557)), .Names = c("CustomerID", "AsOfDate", "distance"
), row.names = c("1", "5", "8", "10", "18", "28", "33", "37", 
"45", "47", "101"), class = "data.frame")

activity.table = structure(list(CustomerID = c(3, 5, 8, 10, 4, 10, 2, 2, 5, 7,
5, 8, 4, 6, 10, 6, 5, 4, 2, 5, 5, 6, 5, 5, 10, 8, 6, 4, 5, 8,
7, 1, 8, 10, 7, 8, 4, 1, 1, 10, 9, 7, 4, 6, 9, 10, 8, 3, 5, 8,
1, 4, 4), ActivityDate = structure(c(1330560000, 1368144000,
1332855900, 1337817600, 1370822400, 1365984000, 1337817600, 1368144000,
1331164800, 1331164800, 1394150400, 1394150400, 1396224000, 1393891200,
1393891200, 1398643200, 1396310400, 1399334400, 1399939200, 1403222400,
1402358400, 1404086400, 1425254400, 1426464000, 1426464000, 1426464000,
1427155200, 1429056000, 1429056000, 1429056000, 1363737600, 1332201600,
1330560000, 1433116800, 1433289600, 1433289600, 1338462000, 1366628400,
1335885300, 1427241600, 1427241600, 1427241600, 1430265600, 1430265600,
1430265600, 1430265600, 1365503400, 1338394200, 1430265600, 1430265600,
1432598400, 1433894400, 1426723200), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct",
"POSIXt")), row.index = 1:53), .Names = c("CustomerID", "ActivityDate",
"row.index"), row.names = c(NA, -53L), class = "data.frame")

 # what does the data look like
> head(activity.table)
  CustomerID        ActivityDate row.index
1          3 2012-03-01 00:00:00         1
2          5 2013-05-10 00:00:00         2
3          8 2012-03-27 13:45:00         3
4         10 2012-05-24 00:00:00         4
5          4 2013-06-10 00:00:00         5
6         10 2013-04-15 00:00:00         6
> head(customer.table)
   CustomerID   AsOfDate   distance
1           1 2015-06-30   2.173805
5           2 2015-06-30  29.402483
8           3 2015-06-30   3.013533
10          4 2015-06-30  18.492314
18          5 2015-06-30 294.878607
28          6 2015-06-30  11.887021
```

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Please also add your desired output.

Comment: is there a mapping between `CustomerID` and `row.index`?

Comment: row.index probably should have been omitted -- sorry. It was just a unique row identifier that wasn't used as a key when I was playing around with data.table.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for a simple rolling join here. First, we will convert to `data.table` objects (please note I'm using the latest version on CRAN for this solution (V 1.9.6+)

```
library(data.table) # V 1.9.6+
setDT(customer.table)
setDT(activity.table)
```

Then, per each row in `customer.table` we will try to join the closest value from `activity.table` while rolling to infinity

```
indx <- activity.table[customer.table, 
                       on = c(CustomerID = "CustomerID",
                              ActivityDate = "AsOfDate"), 
                       roll = Inf,
                       which = TRUE]

indx
# [1] 51 19 48 52 49 44 35 36 45 34  5
```

`indx` is the locations vector of the dates in `activity.table` that are closest to each row in `customer.table`.

Now, all is left is to join back to `customer.table`

```
customer.table[, MostRecentDate := activity.table[indx,ActivityDate]]
customer.table
#     CustomerID   AsOfDate   distance      MostRecentDate
#  1:          1 2015-06-30   2.173805 2015-05-26 00:00:00
#  2:          2 2015-06-30  29.402483 2014-05-13 00:00:00
#  3:          3 2015-06-30   3.013533 2012-05-30 16:10:00
#  4:          4 2015-06-30  18.492314 2015-06-10 00:00:00
#  5:          5 2015-06-30 294.878607 2015-04-29 00:00:00
#  6:          6 2015-06-30  11.887021 2015-04-29 00:00:00
#  7:          7 2015-06-30   9.544386 2015-06-03 00:00:00
#  8:          8 2015-06-30  24.219203 2015-06-03 00:00:00
#  9:          9 2015-06-30  15.006934 2015-04-29 00:00:00
# 10:         10 2015-06-30  10.451366 2015-06-01 00:00:00
# 11:          4 2014-03-07  18.492314 2013-06-10 00:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks for the really clear explanation -- I had a feeling roll was going to be in the solution :)  If the activity.table had a couple more columns that I would like in the final table, is there any easy way to join the tables rather than adding each column individually to the customer.table?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but after crating the index, you could do something like `customer.table[, (cols) := activity.table[indx,  cols, with = FALSE]]` where `cols` is the character vector of the columns you want to extract from `activity.table` and add to `customer.table`

Comment: For your example data set you could try `cols <- c("ActivityDate", "row.index") ; customer.table[, (cols) := activity.table[indx, cols, with = FALSE]]` that will add both `ActivityDate` and `row.index` at once to `customer.table`

Comment: +1 Wondered if it can be done backwards directly something like `customer.table[activity.table, MostRecentDate := ActivityDate, roll=-Inf, on=...]` but then realized that doesn't cope with multiple rows in `customer.table` rolling to the same row in `activity.table`.

Comment: @MattDowle That could indeed be useful and I'm sure you could work it out somehow. Regarding your edit, my initial code was `activity.table[indx, ActivityDate]` actually but then I've changed it to `activity.table[indx]$ActivityDate` becaused assumed that list subsetting is much more efficient, no?

Comment: `$` and `[[` are the best ways to select a single column, yes, and that's what I do.  But not just after `activity.table[indx]` because that creates a new data.table subset for every single column of `activity.table` only then to use one of them.  It's the principle of putting as much inside `[]` as possible so optimization can work.