# Append a date to a data frame based on a condition

Tags: r

I have two data sets with a common ID (Employee number).

Dataset 1 is a list of all the employees and the dates they joined my company. They can be duplicated in this dataset legitimately as they can return to the company at a later date(s).

In Dataset 2 I have a list of all the employees who paid money in to a savings scheme and the date of the transaction. Again, there can be duplicates due to more than 1 payment being made

I'm trying to merge the two datasets together in such a way that the date from Dataset2 is appended to the 'correct' line in Dataset 1. By that I mean appending to the employment record for the employment they were in at the time they made the payment.

I've looked at joining dates as per this solution but the presence of duplicates in my Dataset 1 means this doesn't work
[Data.table: Join on ID and Date key, but want closest date before (or equal to ) date key in first table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33357341/data-table-join-on-id-and-date-key-but-want-closest-date-before-or-equal-to)

Example data from Dataset 1 looks like this

```
Employee    JoinDate
001         01/01/2019
002         01/03/2019
003         01/08/2019
004         01/01/2019
001         01/10/2020
003         01/04/2020
005         01/04/2019
001         01/01/2021
004         01/08/2020
003         01/10/2020
```

Example data from Dataset 2

```
Employee    PayDate
001         01/11/2020
002         01/04/2019
003         01/05/2020
003         01/12/2020
004         01/05/2019
004         01/10/2020
005         01/10/2019
```

Employees can make payments more than once so the issue is tagging each payment to the right employment record.  Payments must come after joining.

For this dummy data the desired output would be:

```
Employee    JoinDate     PayDate
001         01/10/2020   01/11/2019
002         01/03/2019   01/04/2019
003         01/04/2020   01/05/2020
003         01/10/2020   01/12/2020
004         01/01/2019   01/05/2019
004         01/08/2020   01/10/2020
005         01/04/2019   01/10/2019
```

Comment: Hi. Please use `dput(head(df, 10))`  , for example, to provide a sample of your data instead of sceenshots.

Answer (score 1):

`tidyverse` approach.  Thanks @SEAnalyst for creating [toy_data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67841561/2884859)

```r
library(tidyverse)

Dataset1 %>% full_join(Dataset2) %>%
  mutate(across(!Employee, ~as.Date(., format = '%d/%m/%Y'))) %>%
  filter(JoinDate < PayDate) %>%
  group_by(Employee, PayDate) %>%
  slice_tail()

#> Joining, by = "Employee"
#> # A tibble: 7 x 3
#> # Groups:   Employee, PayDate [7]
#>   Employee JoinDate   PayDate   
#>   <chr>    <date>     <date>    
#> 1 001      2020-10-01 2020-11-01
#> 2 002      2019-03-01 2019-04-01
#> 3 003      2020-04-01 2020-05-01
#> 4 003      2020-10-01 2020-12-01
#> 5 004      2019-01-01 2019-05-01
#> 6 004      2020-08-01 2020-10-01
#> 7 005      2019-04-01 2019-10-01
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Simple and beautiful!  I was thinking I would re-write my answer as a function for an `sapply()` or implement the for loop within Rcpp, but now I won't bother.

Comment: If your Dataset1 is not already nicely in date order,  you would need to insert `arrange(Employee, JoinDate)%>%`  between the `filter()` and `group_by()` sections.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Unfortunately this is not working - error "can't find function across".  I'm using R 3.6.1 - perhaps it's too old?  Also, I just made up some data in my example (I don't like putting real data on here as it's commercial). My dates are in the right format already m/d/Y. With that in mind, can i simply drop the ~ as.Date statement in the mutate line?

Comment: ok - i've dropped the mutate line entirely. Now it's telling me "can't find function slice_tail()"

Comment: have you loaded `tidyverse`?  what's the version you are using? @Nottles82

Comment: tidyverse version 1.3.0 and dplyr 0.8.3

Comment: please update `dplyr` to version 1 or above @Nottles82  it is part of [dplyr 1.0.6](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/slice.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how this could be achieved in a for loop.

```
#Your data
Dataset1<- data.frame(
Employee    = c("001",   "002",  "003",  "004",  "001", "003", "005","001" ,"004", "003") ,       
JoinDate =c("01/01/2019","01/03/2019","01/08/2019","01/01/2019","01/10/2020","01/04/2020","01/04/2019","01/01/2021","01/08/2020","01/10/2020"))

Dataset2<-data.frame(
 Employee =c("001" ,        "002" ,       "003" ,        "003" ,        "004" ,       "004",        "005"),      
PayDate = c("01/11/2020","01/04/2019","01/05/2020","01/12/2020","01/05/2019","01/10/2020","01/10/2019"))


#make properly formated dates
Dataset1$JoinDate<-as.Date(Dataset1$JoinDate, "%m/%d/%Y")
Dataset2$PayDate<-as.Date(Dataset2$PayDate, "%m/%d/%Y")

library(dplyr)    
#Make an empty vector equal to the length of the eventual end result. 
my_matches<-vector(mode = "list", length = nrow(Dataset2))

for(i in 1:nrow(Dataset2)){
#Get the index of matching employees
employee_index<- which(Dataset2$Employee[i]== Dataset1$Employee)
#Find/filter dates greater or equal to hire date
filter_new_hire_dates<-Dataset2$PayDate[i] >= Dataset1$JoinDate[employee_index]
#Then get the index of the max hire date of those remaining hire dates
join_index<-employee_index[which.max(Dataset1$JoinDate[employee_index] [filter_new_hire_dates])]
#Join and save to list
my_matches[[i]]<-dplyr::inner_join(Dataset2[i,],Dataset1[join_index,])
}

#contvert to dataframe if that is what you want
Dataset3 <- dplyr::bind_rows(my_matches)
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm concerned about using a loop here. I have (in this particular example) circa 120k records, which will take some time to process using a loop but, if I can get the logic working i'd like to apply this to a very similar set of data which has millions of observations

Comment: I've made a few minor modifications to the original code to hopefully improve your speed.